# Wordpress filters

Tags: wordpress

I used wordpress to make a website with some custom types. The problem is that i need to implement a filter for these types and I have some questions about the plugins that i'm using for this project:

- For to make custom types and views I'm using Types and Views plugins for wordpress.
- I made a new custom type with some fields (title, price, some selectors, ...) and I need to filter all the information ordering the results following 2 criterias. I don't know if is it possible to do so using the Views/Types plugin.
- I also need to filter the fields of the filter. For example, if i have 2 fields one called Countries and other called Cities, if i select Spain in countries I should see only spanish cities in the second field.

Any idea if i can do that using Types and Views plugins? is there any other plugin?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: im not going to answer this tonight...ill just give you a lead....i think what you are looking for is if you choose a form input as 1 value, you want to change the values of another element without refreshing the page? You need jQuery, if you google setting a value from the results of another, you'll get lots of examples.

Answer (score 0):

Any good plugin will save the custom fields as `post-meta`. You need to find out what the key is for the field you are trying to use as a filter. Once you have that you can use a simple meta query to get the posts you need:

```
$args = array(
   'post_type'       => 'post', // The post type
   'posts_per_page'  => -1, // Get all posts
   'orderby'         => 'rand', // Random order, also can use 'post_date' or 'post_title'
   'order'           => 'ASC', // Direction of sort
   'meta_key'        => 'my_meta_key', // Whatever your key is
   'meta_query'      => array(
       array(
           'key'     => 'my_meta_key', // Whatever your key is
           'value'   => 'foo' // What it should be
           'compare' => 'IN', // How to compare the value to the stored value
       )
   )
);
$query = new WP_Query($args); // The query
```

Here is more on the [Wordpress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters).